# Index Values in Listbox

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I have a listbox that is populated with the months of the year as following:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 12
        ListBox1.AddItem MonthName(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

I then store the selected value as a string. What I am interested in is using the equivalent value of i for a calculation instead of the month name.

e.g. If the user has selected July (`i = 7`) what I want to do is store a second string defined as the month prior to the selected string i.e `i - 1` in this case June (`i = 6`).

How do I refer to the value of i in my code as opposed to the name of the month string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ListIndex property of the ListBox, i.e.

```
Debug.Print Listbox1.ListIndex + 1
```

increment by 1 as indices start from 0

be carefull to asume that the previous month is always 1 less than the selected .... what happens if the user selects "January"?

Comment: Great and thanks for heads up on January, hadn't thought about that!